# Using .htaccess to force either HTTP or HTTPS

Tags: http, .htaccess, https

I have already have this code to force these URLs to HTTPS:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/my/?.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my/basket/add?.*$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/login/?.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/logout/?.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/register/?.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/newsletter/?.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/reset-password/?.*$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

And this works really well, but what I want to do is force any URL that *does not* comply with the above conditions to HTTP, firing a 301.

I don't want to create a list of `HTTP` pages and redirect them like I have with the `HTTPS` above. The secure pages URLs will always remain the same, unless I change the system somehow, but I can update them when needed. The non-secure pages can by dynamic, and created / edited by some of the sales team here, therefore these need to be target intelligently.

Any thoughts on how I could do this? It **has** to be done using `.htaccess`, I have been achieving this by handling it within our PHP framework, but this has caused a pretty significant performance problem as well as causing problems with our Google crawls.

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A modification to the answer from Seidr, because in fact you only want to redirect if the HTTPS is on, when you want it to be off (also, there is no %{HTTP} variable). Again, put this after all your rules.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/login/?.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/logout/?.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/register/?.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/newsletter/?.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/reset-password/?.*$
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Haven't tested this though, so not 100% that it will work.

Edit: Conditions for secure pages required, so that they will still be left in HTTPS mode.

Comment: Ok I get it, the `L` flag on my HTTPS `RewriteRule` say that if there's a match there and we're using HTTP then we redirect and that's the last rule processed. But what if we're already using HTTPS? It will ignore my original conditions and redirect back to HTTP... won't it?

Comment: In fact, when I test this it never redirect anything to HTTPS, always to HTTP.

Comment: You're right, you are going to have to add a condition for the secure pages (will require some duplication tho). See edit.

Comment: You will also need to add a condition for the first set of rules.

Comment: Righto, I think I have a small bug in my `.htaccess` so I'll resolve that and try your option... cheers Kazar!

Comment: After spending lots of time adjusting my htaccess file I've managed to get it to work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Nice one, my bad on the bogus HTTP variable. Assumption is the mother of all .... ups, hey.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using the L flag on your rule there, you should be able to just use a RewriteCond such as the one below to rewrite any requests that have not been caught in the previous conditions to HTTP? Place it AFTER the rules you have posted. This seems a bit too obvious, but it might work.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP} OFF
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this will do the trick - I'm way too tired to know for sure! Hopefully it can point you in the right direction though.

Comment: I will try it when I'm back at work tomorrow and report back! Thanks :D